# Symbol on silk screen of design

Tags: pcb, robotics, silkscreen

[image][image]

This is the circuit diagram I used to make my line follower robot. I don't understand the symbol at the right side down corner, the one that is a circle with 3 dots inside. As this is my first PCB design could anybody help?

Comment: Do you have a schematic or a BOM for the circuit? It's probably a potentiometer, but only the BOM will tell you for sure.

Comment: no I don't have either. I refered to this from a site.

Comment: I've added a photo of the sensor panel above.

Comment: There may have been a potentiometer there during beta testing, then it was replaced with a fixed value resistor or a jumper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably a screwdriver-adjusted "trim-pot" (potentiometer). Probably to adjust the sensitivity of the sensors to compensate for different operating conditions (ambient light, etc.).  It looks like the pot is on the OTHER side of the board from what we see in your photo.

You said: "This is the circuit diagram I used to make my line follower robot." but we don't see any circuit diagram. And then you said: "I don't have [a circuit diagram]".  So we are confused what you are doing with this board?  How can you design a PC board without the schematic diagram?